# using aspnet web api for other than rest purposes?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376284/enabling-all-http-verbs-for-web-api-by-default), I am told that web API is specifically purposed for making rest services. What are the options for not wanting to follow rest? What are Web API alternatives to REST?

Answer (score 0):

`WCF` was earlier used to write `RESTful` services. But, **WCF is strongly used towards SOAP based architecture** and doesn't fully support (or it is quite difficult to write) the entirety of RESTful architecture.

Hence, `WebApi` was developed as a lightweight solution to support only RESTful services.